# Is Glue on Chocolate and other Wrappers Safe/ Edible?

Tags: nutrition, diet, side-effects, food-safety, edible

Is the glue from the wrappers on chocolate bars (Yorkie for example) and other foods safe to eat and consume (sometimes it gets stuck on the product)?

I tried researching but came up blank... I am also sure there was a worldwide feud about this not long ago but can't seem to recall any findings from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be trusted as safe as much as the regulations that it comes under can be trusted to make it safe and producers following said regulations.

> Materials and articles that come into contact with food must comply with the rules laid down by European Regulation 1935/2004. The regulation requires that adhesives used in food packaging must not:
>   - affect the food
>   - make the food harmful
>   - change the nature, substance or quality of the food

https://www.nibusinessinfo.co.uk/content/using-adhesives-food-packaging

Comment: Thanks I really don't know why google didn't pick this article up X_X

Comment: sometimes it takes a while of digging, but I don't remember how much it took me to find it